# Getting type mismatch error without any modification in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a code and I didn't make any change, but I am getting `Type mismatch error`. It was working properly previously.

Code :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Intro!A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    r = Application.Match("c", Columns(1), 0)
    c = Application.Match("cc", Rows(1), 0)
    TextBox1.Value = Cells(r, c).Value
    TextBox2.Value = Cells(r, c + 1).Value
    TextBox3.Value = Cells(r, c + 2).Value
    TextBox4.Value = Cells(r, c + 3).Value


End Sub
```

Ran using  `f8` through code found error when reaching here :

```
 c = Application.Match("cc", Rows(1), 0)
```

Objective of this line to find match in first row

Comment: try change `Dim c As Integer` to `Dim c As Variant`

Comment: or change it to `String` if you want to. Currently you assign it as `Integer` but you're look for `String` type

Comment: Is it possible that there used to be a "cc" in row 1 but now there is not?

Comment: Tony M.. it workd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is no 'cc' in first row. In this case `Application.Match` returns an Error object which can't be assigned to an integer.

Comment: Are you sure that there is only this two character string 'cc' in a cell? Maybe try as suggested in first comment: `Dim c As Variant` and watch the result, if there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

When using `Match` you should always prepare your code for the scenario where `Match` failed to find the value (or String) you are looking for.

You can do that by using:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("cc", Columns(1), 0)) Then
```

***Modified Code***

```
Dim r As Variant
Dim c As Variant

Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Intro!A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Not IsError(Application.Match("c", Columns(1), 0)) Then
    r = Application.Match("c", Columns(1), 0)
Else
    ' in case "c" is not found
    MsgBox "critical error finding 'c'"
End If

If Not IsError(Application.Match("cc", Columns(1), 0)) Then
    c = Application.Match("cc", Columns(1), 0)
Else
    ' in case "cc" is not found
    MsgBox "critical error finding 'cc'"
End If
```